# Organize all URLs in one place inside a class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using URLs for HTTP requests all over a class implementation:

```cpp
QNetworkRequest m_request;

m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/details"));
request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/sli"));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/sli/preview"));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/sli/send"));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/sli/download"));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/advanced-sli"));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/profiles/" + ip + ":" + port));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/terminate"));
```

How can I organize all my URLs in one place for tidiness and ease of accessibility?

---

One option is to use `static const` like this on top of the class implementation source file:

```cpp
static const QUrl url1 = QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/details");
static const QUrl url2 = QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/terminate");
static const QUrl url3 = QUrl("http://" + m_IP + ":" + m_Port + "/advanced-sli");

// ...

m_request.setUrl(url1);
m_request.setUrl(url2);
m_request.setUrl(url3);

// ...
```

But the problem is I cannot access members `m_IP` and `m_Port` inside my `static const` definitions.

### UPDATE: solution

Finally, I implemented this on top of class implementation:

```cpp
static const QString routeDetails     = "http://%1:%2/details" ;
static const QString routeSli         = "http://%1:%2/sli" ;
static const QString routeSliPreview  = "http://%1:%2/sli/preview" ;
static const QString routeSliSend     = "http://%1:%2/sli/send" ;
static const QString routeSliDownload = "http://%1:%2/sli/download" ;
static const QString routeAdvancedSli = "http://%1:%2/advanced-sli" ;
static const QString routeProfiles    = "http://%1:%2/profiles/%3:%4" ;
static const QString routeTerminate   = "http://%1:%2/terminate" ;
```

And throughout the implementation I have such statements:

```cpp
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeDetails.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
request.setUrl(QUrl(routeSli.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeSliPreview.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeSliSend.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeSliDownload.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeAdvancedSli.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeProfiles.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port).arg(ip).arg(port)));
m_request.setUrl(QUrl(routeTerminate.arg(m_IP).arg(m_Port)));
```

Comment: Do you know IP and port at compile time? Your Qt version? Do you have specific names for URLs or simple url1, url2, ..., etc. as mentioned in your question?

Comment: @Azeem Yes I know.

Comment: @Azeem Qt is `5.12.6`

Comment: @Azeem URL names might be anything, preferably something meaningful.

Comment: You could just store the strings with placeholders, like `const char* url1="http://{0}:{1}/details"`, and then format them when you use them.

Comment: In general information like urls, paths, filenames and so on go in a configuration file, as you are using Qt I would consider a QSetting and placeholders with QStrig are a good way to handle ip and port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**: This is a subjective problem. The solution may differ depending on one's own use-case and requirements.

---

You can wrap URLs as raw literal strings in a namespace stored in a separate header file (e.g. `urls.hpp`). And, then, you can use [QString::arg()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) to format at runtime with ip:port whenever needed.

Here's an example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QUrl>

namespace url {

static constexpr auto default_ip    = "localhost";
static constexpr auto default_port  = "8080";

static constexpr auto about         = "about";
static constexpr auto services      = "services";
static constexpr auto products      = "products";

QUrl fmt( const QString& route, const QString& ip = default_ip, const QString& port = default_port ) noexcept
{
    static const auto fmt = QString{ "http://%1:%2/%3" };
    return fmt.arg(ip).arg(port).arg(route);
}

} // url

int main()
{
    constexpr auto ip   = "192.168.123.123";
    constexpr auto port = "9090";

    const auto about    = url::fmt( url::about );
    const auto services = url::fmt( url::services );
    const auto products = url::fmt( url::products, ip, port );

    qDebug() << about;
    qDebug() << services;
    qDebug() << products;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
QUrl("http://localhost:8080/about")
QUrl("http://localhost:8080/services")
QUrl("http://192.168.123.123:9090/products")
```

---

You can avoid passing ip:port each time by storing them first if the default ones are not required. The function that returns the formated URL can use those internally without the need of explicit arguments.